# JavaFx: How to make an fx:include to fill the parent pane

Tags: javafx, include, fxml, tabview

I want to build a tab view. I like to put the content of each tab in a separate FXML file.

With `<fx:include source="Details.fxml" />` I can import an FXML into my main FMXL. The import works fine but unfortunately the Details.fxml content is only using the prefHeight and prefWidth defined in the Details.fxml. How can I configure that the included FXML uses the entire of the parent (the tab pane).

My Details.fxml view contains a TableView and the table should always use the entire width of window. Also if I resize the window.

Thanks for any hints.

Regards,
Manuel

Comment: Can't you just remove the `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` from Details.fxml?